# Pathauto is not updating child urls when the parent url is changed

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, token, pathauto

my pathauto settings for nodes are

```
[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]/[node:title]/
```

if i change the url of a menu parent, the urls for child nodes are not updated.
for example i have

```
category-xyz/
category-xyz/node1/
category-xyz/node2/
```

if i change the category to category-abc the urls for the nodes are still the same.
even mass update is not working, i have to manually update all nodes.
is there no other way for this problem?

Comment: This is usual when you change the patter using pathauto. You need to go to child term(s) and remove the path previously set by un-checking 'Automatic URL' and then again check it. Once you save it, it will automatically have the path with the pattern you set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **Node Hierarchy** can fix this problem : https://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy